# File Navigation in Zathura

Tags: zathura

What is the best way to find and open a file in Zathura? I typically open Zathura using Rofi, and if I'm trying to open a file I haven't opened before I usually issue the :open command followed by the full path of the file. That is somewhat tedious to do if I can't remember the full path and filename off the top of my head. Is there a better way to do this?